# In JFace Databinding, Is it possible to cancel an change in widget if its validation fail?

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface, eclipse-databinding

When dealing with combo-box viewer, its selection is binded and a validator is set for it. 
I'm wondering if it is possible to cancel the change of the selection if the selection presents a invalid value?

The reason why i'm asking this, is that when the change happened, if the validator fail on this change, the model will not be updated. However, the widget still got changed; in this case, it looks to me that the widget and the model are in inconsistent state.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This is normal behavior. When you type in text field and validation doesn't pass, the text field gets e.g. red, but its text is still there (although wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should invoke `org.eclipse.core.databinding.Binding.updateModelToTarget()` to sync values from Model to Target as soon as  validation fails.